# CSS Building a navigation bar using :before and :after inserting bracket image but :before bracket missing

Tags: css, wordpress

I am building a navigation bar and need to have a bracket inserted before the button and after the button to highlight the button when hovered and selected as below example

```
[  Button 1  ]    button 2    button 3    button 4
```

I am using an image for the bracket width=7px height=30px. My CSS is limited and I’m teaching myself! I have managed to get it all to work if I use **position: relative** as below

```
#np-access a:hover:before{ 
  content: url(images/bracket-left.png); 
  position:relative;
  top: 10px; 
}

#np-access a:hover:after {
   content: url(images/bracket-right.png); 
   position:relative;
   top: 10px;
}
```

But this causes the navigation to ‘**bounce**’ , button moves to the right when hovered over.
I changed this and used **position: absolute** which works, however the brackets display over the text (narrow) . To spread them apart a bit,  I’ve added **left: 0.5px** for **:before** and **right: 0.5px** for **:after** which works, but the first bracket is missing and the others appear ok but are too close ie button 2 right bracket is too close to button 3 left bracket (no padding), but they function correctly (example below).

```
   button 1  ][   button 2   ][  button 3  ][  button 4  ]
```

To try and add some padding to the brackets (button 2 right bracket too close to button 3 left bracket) I increased the padding for the anchor attribute from **1.5em** to **2em** but the brakets followed, and the appearance stayed the same

```
#np-access a {
color: #5F5B5B; 
display: block;
line-height: 3.333em;
padding: 0 1.5em;
text-decoration: none;


}
```

Why is the first bracket missing when using position absolute? And how do I add padding? Hope someone can offer an explanation as to where I am going wrong! Thanks in advance my CSS is below

```
#np-access .current-menu-item > a:after,
#np-access .current-menu-ancestor > a:after,
#np-access .current_page_item > a:after,
#np-access .current_page_ancestor > a:after {
 content: url(images/bracket-right.png); 
 position:absolute;
 right: 0.5px;
 top: 10px;
}

#np-access .current-menu-item > a:before,
#np-access .current-menu-ancestor > a:before,
#np-access .current_page_item > a:before,
#np-access .current_page_ancestor > a:before {
     content: url(images/bracket-left.png); 
     position:absolute;
     left: -0.5px;
     top: 10px; 
}


#np-access a:hover:before{ 
    content: url(images/bracket-left.png); 
    position:absolute;
    left: -0.5px;
    top: 10px; 
}

#np-access a:hover:after {
    content: url(images/bracket-right.png); 
    position:absolute;
    right: 0.5px;
    top: 10px;
```

}

## code which now works

```
#np-access a:hover:before{ 
   content: url(images/bracket-left.png); 
    position:absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 10px; 
    padding: 0 10px;
 }

 #np-access a:hover:after {
    content: url(images/bracket-right.png); 
    position:absolute;
    right: 0.5px;
    top: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
```

Thanks dagfr!

Comment: you probably miss position: relative; for #np-access a

Comment: Thanks dmi3y added position: relative to #np-access a but made no difference I'm afraid putting left: 0px; they all show but first before bracket does not show, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -0.5px left cause the first bracket to be out of the page.

Why don't have left:0 right:0 on :before and :after but a padding added to #np-access a:hover like padding: 0 3px; ??

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help! @dagfr done as suggested but brackets went everywhere I removed the padding and put left: 0px; and kept the rest but left bracket still does not show??

Comment: I have had a go changing part of what you suggested dagfr and I have managed to get it to work what you suggested was correct ;) please see what i added to get it to work with your suggestion!!  please see amended code above thanks